# iPawn library for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, touchscreen

I found lot of iPad apps that use iPawn to interact with real objects posed on the capacitive touch screen of the device. I'm interested to know how this interaction it's possible and I'm interested to know if I can use iPawn to develop iPad/iPhone apps, there's a library or something I can use to implements iPawn in my apps?
The company who developed this technology is [volumique](http://volumique.com/v2/en/), but I can't understand if exist a free sdk that I can use to develop my own apps or I should buy the sdk.
Thank you